# Google Play Store - Closed Track APK Update

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app in production (v1) on Play Store.

I've been working on some updates to bring the app up to date, namely:

- 64 bit compatibility
- minimum API/target SDK update to newer versions

I want to test this on the closed track and I've already set up an 'Alpha' release (v2).

My problem is that on the v2 Alpha release screen I get a note saying that APK v1 is to be deactivated under a section labelled `Android App Bundles and APKs to deactivate`.

My question is:

**Will pushing this v2 APK to Alpha affect the live app in any way? (I'm wondering if the API/SDK/64bit change might cause issues)**

Answer (score 0):

For reference - pushing the 'Alpha' APK live has no effect on the Production track. The warning simply refers to the v1 APK within the Alpha (Closed) track.